# IntelliJ 14 IDEA - Can't find the correct path to a file

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, intellij-idea, path

I am trying to test one of my classes in IntelliJ IDEA 14 through android test in the run/debug configurations. The problem that I have is that I can't seem to locate the path to a file which has stumped me for a bit.

The location of my file is under:

```
main/tests/res/xml/myfile.xml
```

And here is my source code:

```
public final void testMain() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File file = new File( myfile.xml );

    Log.d( TAG, "Current sys dir: " + curDir);
    Log.d( TAG, "Current abs dir: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    Log.d(TAG, "Exists?: " + file.exists());

    if (!file.exists()) {
        fail( "Failed to find file: " +
                file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

And here are my Log outputs ( Sorry for the formatting ):

```
Current sys dir: /
Current abs dir: /myfile.xml
Exists?: false
Failed to find file: /myfile.xml
```

Why is it that my current sys dir only a forward slash? And how would I get the full path from "/" to "myfile.xml"

Thanks.

Comment: Use the class path! Never make assumptions about directory structure.

Comment: So would I have to do new File( "main/tests/res/xml/myfile.xml" ) ?

Answer (score 3):

You specify the working directory in IntelliJ idea in your run/debug configuration. In your IntelliJ toolbar, look for the run icon (a green triangle). There should be a drop-down just to the left of the run icon. Click on the drop-down. Click **edit configurations**. Select your configuration and set the **working directory** to whatever you need.

When you run your program from IntelliJ (or start debugging), IntelliJ sets the working directory for your application to whatever you specified above. There is no way to stop IntelliJ from setting the directory. All relative paths in your program will be relative to this directory. Your program can find the directory using **System.getProperty("user.dir")**.

Comment: There is no working directory in Android Tests, unless I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Olva, do you see a run icon (green triangle) in IntelliJ toolbar? Do you see a drop-down next to it?

Comment: Yes I understand. I am trying to test one of my non-activity classes which extends TestCase, and I created a new configuration under "Android Tests" and there is no working directory. Maybe I'm supposed to use something else? Here is where I am at: http://gyazo.com/afc644d46786baecb864e4fce5119d82